# JSP is not getting the updated String value

Tags: jsp, attributes, textarea, refresh

I want to display something like "log" on the page, I am using textarea for it. I have timer that runs every seconds and calls Test.getConsole(), but once the jsp page is loaded it is not refreshing. The method Test.getConsole() returns always the same value even if it has new text. When I refresh the page (F5) new content of Test.getConsole() displays. How to make the process of (F5) automatic ? I want real-time update of my text area with the right text that  Test.getConsole() is returning.

JSP:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>MultiMine - Home</title>
    <script>
        function timer() {
            document.getElementById("1").value = "<%=Test.getConsole()%>";
            window.setTimeout("timer()", 1000);
        }
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="1" name="output" style="width:1194px" rows="40"></textarea>
<script>
    timer();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Java:

```
public static String console = "Console initializing...";

public static String getConsole() {
    return console;
}

    public static void startConsole() {
   Timer t = new Timer();
    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
        int i = 0;
        public void run() {
            try {
                console = console + "\\r" + i;
                i++;
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };
    t.schedule(tt, 1000, 1000);
}
```

In the textarea I can see the only "Console initializing..." and I need to refresh (F5) to see "Console initializing... 1 2 3 4 etc.." (the timer output). How to "update" the String ?

Answer (score 0):

The scriptlet <%=Test.getConsole()%> is being executed before the page is loaded. The JSP receives the initial value of the method as plain text, so the Javascript is actually

```
<script>
    function timer() {
        document.getElementById("1").value = "Console Initializing...";
        window.setTimeout("timer()", 1000);
    }
</script>
```

Javascript cannot call the Java code so easily. A new request must be made to the page to get the scriptlet re-evaluated. To automate it, you will need to use Ajax.

Comment: Thanks for reply. And could you please show any simple example how to get String from java method using ajax and insert it into a var ?